# Android Studio Logcat not showing Log messages with ADB over Wi-Fi

Tags: android, debugging, tcp, adb, logcat

My device is connected using `adb tcpip` and the Logcat is not showing `Log.i(TAG, "message")`. Running `abd logcat` does not show the  `Log.i(TAG, "message")` either. When using emulators or USB-connected devices, it is working fine. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

On your Android device, in Settings->System->Developer Settings, there is an option (off by default) that says "Enable Wi-Fi Verbose Logging."

Answer (score 2):

Also restart your phone after changing the phone setting, if not working. Make sure to select the correct device used for debugging in logcat window.

Answer (score 1):

also,
In the Device's Developer OptionS: make sure Logger Buffer sizes is NOT set to off

I would set it to the highest if your device can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is this...

1. Activate "Enable Wi-Fi Verbose Logging" on your android Device
2. Add "ADB Wifi" to android studio
3. Run the app on your phone using cable (and make sure logs show)
4. Connect the phone using ADB, then remove the cable from phone.
   [image]

Please note that: Step 3 might seem useless but it seems important because it acts as a way to authorize your phone to send logs when you go wireless. There after remove the cable, the logs will show.